Sonarlint refactor this repetition that can lead to stack overflow regex expression
I have to write a java regular expression to find if a string has at least 6 digits in it. The digits may be separated by space, hyphen or other characters.
The java pattern that I wrote "^(?=.(?:\d[\s-]){6,}).*$"  is working fine. However, Sonarlint is saying that I should refactor this repetition that can lead to stack overflow for large inputs.
String patternString1 = ".(\d[\s-]){6,}.";
String patternString2= "^(?=.(?:\d[\s-]){6,}).$"

both of the above cause the same warning - need to change it since regular expression should not overflow the stack.
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {     
        String[] strings = { "JamesBond1.zip", "JamesBond 1 2 3456.zip", "JaneBond X 3-4-2024"};        
        String patternString = ".*(\\d[\\s-]*){6,}.*";     
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);      
        for (String s : strings) {         
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);         
            if (matcher.matches()) {             
                System.out.println("\"" + s + "\" matches the pattern.");         
            } else {             
                System.out.println("\"" + s + "\" does not match the pattern.");         
            }     
        } 
    }
}

The first string should fail and the 2nd and 3rd should pass.

Try: ^(?:.*[0-9]){6}.*$

by the way, no need to use ^ and $ if using matches() - it already requires that the whole input matches the expression

"may be separated by space, hyphen or other characters": so by any character? Then why does your regex only allow spaces and hyphens between the digits that match? Also your regex only allows one such character between matching digits. Is this the rule, or can there be more than one character between digits that match? Can you clarify?

@trincot For now, I am told to lookout for spaces and hyphens. The search for these characters is on repeat. I guess that's what causing the stack overflow warning for Sonar

Try:
^\D*(?:\d\D?){6}.*$

See regex101
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = { "JamesBond1.zip", "JamesBond 1 2 3456.zip", "JaneBond X 3-4-2024" };
        String patternString = "^\\D*(?:\\d\\D?){6}.*$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        for (String s : strings) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                System.out.println("\"" + s + "\" matches the pattern.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("\"" + s + "\" does not match the pattern.");
            }
        }
    }
}

which returns
"JamesBond1.zip" does not match the pattern.
"JamesBond 1 2 3456.zip" matches the pattern.
"JaneBond X 3-4-2024" matches the pattern.

See: Online Java Compiler

Explanation
To avoid backtracking get rid of nested * + + or {n,} constructs and try to be more explicit with regards of multiple entries being able to goble up the same thing. See character classes:

^: Match the start of line
\D*: Match anything up to the first digit
(?:...){6}: match 6 times

\d\D?: a digit followed, optionally, by a non digit (like: space, hyphen or other characters)


.*$: after you found the 6 digits match the rest of the line


I am still getting error in the highlighted code below.
Sonarlint is highlighting these characters (?:     )
and still showing the same error.
I can add a screenshot if someone can let me know how to add it.

(?: )
these characters
